# Numeric Value Comparison in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to know how to get a numeric value in TCL. What I mean is that, if the value is not numeric, result should fail else pass.

The below is what I have tried;

```
set trueKIND false
set trueKINDlist [list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

if {[lsearch -exact $trueKINDlist $Registrant(KIND)] >= 0} {
    set trueKIND true
}
```

But what happens if the value of trueKINDlist > 10, this code certainly will fail...

Can somebody please tell me how I can write this in TCL? Or assist me with the operator to use in achieving this...

Thanks
Mattie

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. If one of the elements of `trueKINDlist` is `10`, it does not look like the code will fail. [Example](http://codepad.org/fLazrXqG)

Comment: If the element of trueKINDlist is 11, The code will fail since 11 is not in the list. So i want the code to be able to read all numeric values. Such that if the element is not numeric, it should fail

Comment: If 11 is not in the list, then you will get -1 from `lsearch` and `trueKIND` remains false. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Ok, I think I'm beginning to understand. If you want to make `trueKIND` become `true` for any numeric value of `Registrant(KIND)`, then you could use [`string is`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M10) and then use the class that suits you best. Right now, it seems like you could make use of digit, double or integer, depending on what kind of number you are considering as numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the string by `[string is ...]` procedure. For example:

```
set trueKIND [string is integer -strict $Registrant(KIND)]
```

Reference: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M10

Comment: also, you can perform other validations, for example: `if { [string is integer -strict $variable] && $variable > 1 && $variable <= 10 } { set trueKIND true }`

Comment: Thank you Chpock, This does not cater for all numeric value. What if the element of trueKIND is >10 or any other numeric value? What i am trying to achieve is that if the element of trueKIND is not numeric, It should fail else pass

Answer (score 1):

You've got to think what kind of validation you want. For example, if you want to just validate that the value is an integer, *any* integer, do this:

```
if {![string is entier -strict $value]} {
    error "$value is not an integer"
}
```

(There is also `string is integer`, but that uses a restricted 32-bit range for historical reasons, and `string is wide` uses a 64-bit range. For floating point numbers, use `string is double`. The `-strict` is required here; without it the empty string is also accepted; again, this is for historical reasons.)

When you have a particular range you want the value to be in, you use a compound condition:

```
if {![string is entier -strict $value] || !($value >= 0 && $value <= 10)} {
    error "$value is not an integer in the range (0..10)"
}
```

If you are doing this a lot, use a procedure to make it clearer:

```
proc IntegerInRange {value lowerBound upperBound} {
    expr {[string is entier -strict $value] && $value >= $lowerBound && $value <= $upperBound}
}

if {![IntegerInRange $value 0 10]} {
    error "$value is not an integer in the range (0..10)"
}
if {![IntegerInRange $value2 3 25]} {
    error "$value2 is not an integer in the range (3..25)"
}
```